# Trying to log to file on nodejs with 'log' package from npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log).  I've followed the example code from the docs:

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , Log = require('log')
  , log = new Log('debug', fs.createWriteStream('my.log'));
```

But then what?  How do I send actual log info to the file?  I want what normally gets logged with `console.log()` to go to the file.

edit: here's the context that I am using it in, as a minimal example.  `log.info()` works fine outside of the while. As it is below, the file is created but has nothing in it.

```
var fs = require('fs')
var Log = require('log')
var log = new Log('info', fs.createWriteStream('my.log'));

while(true) {
    log.info("testing");
}
```

Comment: Don't use `while (true)` like that in Node.js, it blocks the event loop preventing any I/O (like writing to a file) from happening.

Comment: I need the script to run repeatedly and continuously

Comment: surely there's some code that you want to run in between the calls to the logger?

Comment: Yeah, there is.  I just tried the above in my actual code and it does work fine.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// (taken from readme of package)
log.debug('preparing email');
log.info('sending email');
log.error('failed to send email');
```

These will each log to the file you specified. The function denotes the log level, and is prepended to the data you provide.

Comment: I tried `log.info("...")` and nothing was written.  The file is created but nothing written to it.

Comment: @erv please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. It works for me.

Comment: Ok, give me a little bit of time.  My head is immersed in another problem just at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fs.appendFileSync() method in order to add content synchronously to the log you are creating.

```
var fs require('fs')
,Log = require('log')
,log = new Log('debug', fs.createWriteStream('test.txt'));

log.debug('test test');
log.debug('test sadasd');
log.debug('test xcvxcv');
log.debug('test ewrewr');
log.debug('test hjgj');
log.debug('test fghfh');
log.debug('test yuiyui');
```

Comment: That's not using the log package, though, is it?

Comment: If you need it to sync with your log commands then wrap the fs.appendFileSync in your logging as follows.

log = new Log('debug', fs.appendFileSync('log.txt'));

Comment: @FernandoGarcia the `Log` constructor requires a stream, and `fs.appendFileSync` doesn't return one.

Comment: @robertklep correct use createWriteStream method instead. Just call the log.debug method.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log) package is not designed to log `Console.log()` statement. As per my knowledge every log file have **date/time/(log type) and information related to it.** So normal `console.log()` also have same info stored into it. 
 
[Log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log) package which you mentioned is used to create user defined logs of any type (info,debug,warning etc etc.).